# How to use a wordpress blog plugin on an external php page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a php website with a wordpress blog (located on folder called "blog") and I want to use plugins like wp rocket to speed up other php pages. How to do so?

Comment: you use a php cache mechanism like opcache instead. wp plugins are for wp

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you please let me know how to use OPCACHE? i never heared about it

Comment: a quick google search of "php caching opcache" is better help. if you run into any issues - create a new question here